# Why Linq.Dynamic.Core query with datetime property is translated to TO_TIMESTAMP

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq, dynamic-linq

I'm using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core version 1.0.7.6 with EF and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 12.1.2400.

Any idea why dynamic query like

```
EntitySet.Where($"Date == @0", date)
```

is translated to sql :

```
SELECT * FROM "Schema"."Entities" "Extent1"
WHERE (TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-02-12 00:00:00.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') = "Extent1"."Date")
```

Notice the `TO_TIMESTAMP` function call.

While standard Linq query on the same context and the same set

```
EntitySet.Where(p => p.Date == date)
```

is translated to :

```
SELECT * FROM "Schema"."Entities" "Extent1" 
WHERE ("Extent1"."Date" = :p__linq__0)
```

No `TO_TIMESTAMP` function call

Comment: What do you think `:p__linq__0` does?

Comment: What is the type and value of the `date` variable?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem if you saying that when oracle provides parameter value it will call TO_TOMESTAMP - fair enough. But then I would change my question to why is dynamic linq query without parameter. Or how do I make those two queries to generate the same sql?

Comment: @mjwills its a DateTime variable with value of '2016-02-12 00:00:00.000'

Comment: The second binds a parameter that is already of the appropriate type, the first does not. Why not? Likely to avoid any problems with expressions that can't be translated using parameters where the SQL engine doesn't allow it (even though that's no problem here), but that's speculating on behalf of the `Linq.Dynamic.Core` authors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that the way you are using it, Dynamic LINQ binds the passed variables *by value*, which is equivalent of using *constant* values inside the static query. The equivalent static LINQ would be

```
EntitySet.Where(p => p.Date == new DateTime(2016, 02, 12))
```

which will translate the same way as the sample dynamic query.

If you wish to let Dynamic LINQ bind the variables as parameters to the resulting query, you can use anonymous type with properties like this:

```
EntitySet.Where($"Date == @0.date", new { date })
```

which will be translated the same way as your sample static query.

Comment: That in deed helped but now it uses CAST on the column in generated SQL. 'SELECT * FROM "Schema"."Entities" "Extent1" 
WHERE (( CAST( "Extent1"."Date" AS date)) = :p__linq__0)'

Comment: I don't see any difference between the static and dynamic LINQ query expression trees (except the closure class name), thus no any reason they to be translated differently to SQL. Unfortunately can't test on Oracle.

Comment: @IvanStoev `"Date == @0.date", new { date = new DateTime(2016, 02, 12) }` is absolute genious. (made a small edit BTW). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over this old question while I had the same problem with the current version of System.Linq.Dynamic.Core. To fix it in the current version you just have to enable the `UseParameterizedNamesInDynamicQuery` config option like this for example:

```
var config = new ParsingConfig
{
    UseParameterizedNamesInDynamicQuery = true,
};
query.Where(config, CommandText, ParameterList.ToArray());
```